# I have a question about the Flutter plugin

Tags: flutter

I would like to ask, if the JAR package and SO file of the Flutter Plugin are integrated into the Bug package of the Flutter app project, will the resource package of the Flutter app be integrated into the bug package? I didn't see the SO file I wanted in the DEBUG package.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In the question, you mean `Debug` instead of `Bug` package no?